# f:ajax does not render target components in jsf app

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, jsf, tomcat

I am programming a Web-Application with Java EE, JSF, Hibernate, MySQL by using Eclipse and Apache Tomcat. I do not use Spring, EJB or etc.

In the beginning, I saw that components, whose ids are written in "render" parts of code below, were updated. However, after some code development, I realized that f:ajax does not update these components anymore. Also, functions (prepareTempUsrGrp and prepareTempUsr) in the bean - "adminPanelFacade" were not fired.  I got back to the version of the application which worked properly, but that version also does not work, now!

```
<input jsfc="h:commandButton" id="usrGrpHiddenBtn" class="hiddenBtn"  action="#{adminPanelFacade.prepareTempUsrGrp}">
    <f:ajax execute="adminPanelForm" render="grpDetNameInp managerPanel planMngmnt alarmMngmnt raporMngmnt devRegMngmnt energyCons mntnncLifeTime logMngmnt" />
</input>
<input jsfc="h:commandButton" id="usrHiddenBtn" class="hiddenBtn" action="#{adminPanelFacade.prepareTempUsr}">
    <f:ajax execute="adminPanelForm" render="usrDetUsrName usrDetUsrGrpName usrDetPass usrDetFName usrDetLName usrDetAddress usrDetTel usrDetMail" />
</input>
```

Some component example;

```
...
<tr class="grpDetTblRghtRow">
    <td>
        <input jsfc="h:selectBooleanCheckbox" id="managerPanel" title="Yönetici Paneli" value="#{adminPanelFacade.tempUsrGrp.ADMINISTRATOR_SCR}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span jsfc="h:outputText" value="Yönetici Paneli"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grpDetTblRghtRow">
    <td>
        <input jsfc="h:selectBooleanCheckbox" id="planMngmnt" title="Planlama Yönetimi" value="#{adminPanelFacade.tempUsrGrp.PLANNING_SCR}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span jsfc="h:outputText" value="Planlama Yönetimi"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grpDetTblRghtRow">
    <td>
        <input jsfc="h:selectBooleanCheckbox" id="alarmMngmnt" title="Alarm Yönetimi" value="#{adminPanelFacade.tempUsrGrp.ALARM_MNGMNT_SCR}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span jsfc="h:outputText" value="Alarm Yönetimi"/>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

If I delete f:ajax lines, it works and functions of the bean are fired. But, I do not want to refresh all the page. I want to update only specific components, so I need this solution.
I know that component ids are right. Also, I do not see any Java exception on console.

I removed server configurations from Eclipse. I deleted Tomcat 7.0 and installed again. I created new server in Eclipse. However, nothing happened. It still does not work!

All feedback greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
There is new information! The app works properly in another computer same as working in my computer before my last code development. May there be any corruption in my browser, Eclipse, Tomcat etc.? Although I fix the problem, is there any risk of corruption in browser, Eclipse etc. again when I continue using f:ajax in my code?

**SOLUTION:**
It is so weird, but the problem is solved after some different changes on the infrastructure of my application.
1) I upgraded Tomcat 7.0 from 32-bit version to 64-bit version.
2) I upgraded JSF libraries, that are worked in server-side(localhost), from (jsf-api-2.2.0-m03.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.0-m03.jar) to (jsf-api-2.2.6.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.6.jar)
3) After upgrades, it did not work. Then, I changed the form-id of .xhtml page. I ran the app, I saw that it worked! Then, I changed back the form-id. It still worked!

I think there is a bug in infrastructure of the system (Eclipse, JSF libraries or Tomcat) I work on. I hope I won't meet such an error again.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change the "execute"

```
<f:ajax execute="adminPanelForm" render="grpDetNameInp managerPanel planMngmnt alarmMngmnt raporMngmnt devRegMngmnt energyCons mntnncLifeTime logMngmnt" />
```

to

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render="grpDetNameInp managerPanel planMngmnt alarmMngmnt raporMngmnt devRegMngmnt energyCons mntnncLifeTime logMngmnt" />
```

Maybe even adding an `event` param.

I suspect you want to rerender the id's when something happens to the input rather then on form submit.

I'm not 100% sure if this works for you. It works for me, but i dont know the what/why of the `<a4j:ajax>` component

Comment: @W vd L, I try with "@this" and "event='click'", but action function is not fired, again. After you advise, I add <a4j:ajax> line with "xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" and "xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j". However, the app works as if there is no <a4j:ajax> line and when I click related button, whole paper is refreshed.